# How to retrieve values for key 2 into NSString?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring, nsarray, nsmutabledictionary

How to retrieve values for key 2 of a NSMutableDictionary into NSString?

My response data is given

```
response{ 0 = { email = "grover@gmail.com"; firstname = Grover; }; 1 = { email = "hems@gmail.com"; firstname = Gems; }; 2 = { email = "rohit@gmail.com"; firstname = Rohit; }; }
```

Comment: response{ 0 = { email = "grover@gmail.com"; firstname = Grover; }; 1 = { email = "hems@gmail.com"; firstname = Gems; }; 2 = { email = "rohit@gmail.com"; firstname = Rohit; }; }

Comment: can you show ur tried code

Comment: Don't post code / data in a comment, edit your question and format it correctly with the provided tools

Answer (score 1):

```
NSDictionary *key2 = response[@"2"];
NSString *email = key2[@"email"];
NSString *firstname = key2[@"firstname"];
```